# Importing modules with "PIP" with a distribution error

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pyqt4

I recently attempted to import gtk, webkit and PyQt4 via pip in the command line. This error struck when I tried importing each of modules stated above:

```
     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from       versions: )
    No matching distribution found for PyQt4
```

To remove any misunderstanding, the above error was for ALL modules not just PyQt4. In an attempt to fix this problem, I believed that the modules were already installed so I headed over to my python IDLE and tried importing them. When I did, I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'
```

Again, this happened to all modules.

I then tried removing ALL versions of python on my computer and re-installed ONLY 3.6.0 but error persisted.

If anyone could give me a solution that would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Given the answer below, you should precise which operation system you're using...

Comment: @liberforce Windows 32bit! Also, Ii tried using sudo in the command line but it just says sudo is not a internal or external command!

Comment: You should add your pip command line too... Python can't find the modules, but that's normal if installation with pip failed.